# How to print contents in clr winforms empty project c++?

Tags: winforms, visual-c++, printing, desktop-application

I am using **clr winforms .Net Framework and C++** to build a desktop app. in **VS**.

I have a panel and over that panel, I've textboxes and labels.

I want to **print** all the contents of the panel. How can I do that.
And I also want a print preview dialog.

Kindly help me on this.

I tried the printpreviewdialog and printdocument tools but failed in writting the code.

Comment: Can you please [**Edit**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75661633/edit) your post and show the code for the attempts you made e.g. with `PrintPreviewDialog`, and also say _specifically_ what didn't work about it. For example, did it fail to compile? Was there a runtime error? etc.

Comment: Actually, I don't know how to use these tools. Kindly share the code if possible on how to print the contents of a panel in c++ clr winforms empty project.